# Can WriterT be made covariance? Can WriterT[F[_], W, A] be declared with +A instead?

Tags: scala, covariance, scalaz

I have code like:

```
type StringValidation[+A] = Validation[String, A]
type WriterValidation[A] = WriterT[StringValidation, String, A]
type Result[A] = WriterValidation[A]

private def someResult: Result[Int]
def implementTrait: Result[Any] = someResult    // type mismatch
```

it gives type mismatch, found `Result[Int]`, required `Result[Any]`, but if I change it to:

```
type WriterValidation[+A] = WriterT[StringValidation, String, A]
```

it gives "covariant type A occurs in invariant position in WriterT..."

it occurs to me that the operation should be Okay in concept, `Validation` can be covariance, why `WriterT` could not (or is not) decared `WriterT[F[_], W, +A]` (or even with `+W`)?

I'm using scalaz7 snapshot, but I see that the declaration of WriterT in 6.0.4 is the same.

---

Solved.
it turns out that I used the wrong version, what I used was `"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0-SNAPSHOT"`, once I switched to `"org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.9.2" % "7.0.0-M2"` it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your situation, but scalaz-seven tree (and also the M2 release) has  [covariant type args](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/WriterT.scala).

```
    sealed trait WriterT[F[+_], +W, +A] { ...
```

Also the following works:

```
    scala> type SV[+A] = Validation[String, A]
defined type alias SV

scala> type WV[+A] = WriterT[SV, String, A]
defined type alias WV

scala> type Result[+A] = WV[A]
defined type alias Result

scala> def someResult: Result[Int] = ???
someResult: Result[Int]

scala> def implementTrait: Result[Any] = someResult
implementTrait: Result[Any]
```

Comment: it turns out that I used the wrong version, what I used was `"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0-SNAPSHOT"`, once I switched to `"org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.9.2" % "7.0.0-M2"` it's ok